How to implement a `foreach` function inside a class in C++ that takes other member functions as parameters?
Let's say we have a class that contains a vector. This class also has some member functions that manipulate the elements of that vector given and index, e.g., like this:
class Foo
{
   std::vector v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   
   void a(int i){ v[i]++; }
   void b(int i){ v[i]--; }
}

I now regularly have to call these functions on each element, so I implement another member function that uses a for loop. Maybe like this:
/* inside Foo */
void for_each_a()
{
   for (int i{0}; i<v.size(); i++) a(i);
}

But implementing this for many different functions in my class would be a lot of duplicate code. Is there not a more elegant solution that uses the member functions as parameters? Something like this:
/* inside Foo */
for_each(a);

How would I implement this for_each and would this be a "good practice" thing to do?
Thanks for your help.

Why can't you use std::for_each or a range for loop, together with a suitable lambda?

A good practice would be for Foo to have methods that mean something, rather than allowing users to modify vector elements directly. But that's a design discussion and we don't know anything concrete about Foo.

@Jarod42 oh yes you’re right. I updated the post. Thank you.


would this be a "good practice" thing to do?

Yes. As written, you want member function pointers (I also replaced int with std::size_t):
void for_each(void (Foo::*func)(std::size_t i))
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        (this->*func)(i);
}

for_each(&Foo::a);

But perhaps a better idea is to make the functions accept raw numbers, rather than indices (either by reference, or by value and return a modified number). Then you don't have to limit for_each to the member functions of the same class, and your a,b become static (or can be made non-member).
Then you choose between templating the function (if it's small enough to be in the header):
void for_each(auto &&func)
{
    for (int &elem : v)
        func(elem);
}

void a(int &elem){ ++elem; }

for_each(a);

Or accepting std::function, which is slower but lets you hide the definition of for_each() in a .cpp file:
void Foo::for_each(std::function<void(int &)> func)
{
    for (int &elem : v)
        func(elem);
}

Note that in C++26 you should use std::function_ref in this case instead of std::function.

Or template<auto memfun> void for_each() { ... }

@康桓瑋: you disallow stateful functors (as capture-lambda).

@Jarod42 I'm not sure if they suggested that as an alternative to the first snippet or the second one.
